# kineticJS sprite animation malfunction in iPad and android browser

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I’m having a problem with the use of sprite sheets in mobile browsers (ipad/android), a strange behavior occurs, the stage is multiplied and scaled down multiple times when i click on a sprite animation, everything works fine until the click occurs.
Any hint?
The only browser that it doesn’t occurs is the safari from the ios 6 beta in ipad 2. In the native android browser the error happens but in android chrome everything works fine.
In desktop browsers everything works fine.

UPDATE: the problem is the afterFrame, the error is that the index is not valid. I don't understand... what does the afterFrame? i have 7 frames and it gives error if the after frame is superior to 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you using?  This sounds like a bug that has been fixed in v4.0.1.

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log